# ClassLoader.loadLibrary NullPointerException running tests

Tags: java, gradle, classloader

I have a Gradle based project, running CI tests using Github Action. One of the modules is based on a native library, and loads it as `System.loadLibrary(LIBNAME)`.

It all works fine on dev machine, but unfortunately always fails on CI with:

```
     java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at io.emeraldpay.polkaj.tx.TestKeys.<clinit>(TestKeys.groovy:24)
        ...

        Caused by:
        java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2646)
            at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
            at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
            at io.emeraldpay.polkaj.schnorrkel.Schnorrkel.<clinit>(Schnorrkel.java:303)
            ... 7 more
```

The `ClassLoader.java:2646` is just:

```
2646: for (String sys_path : sys_paths) {
```

It's possible because in my class (`Schnorrkel` here) I force ClassLoader to re-initialize values of `usr_paths` and `sys_path` after adding native lib to those paths. I do that in class's `static` block, which is supposed to be run only once.

It all looks like there is a race between different `static` initialzers, which is possible if there are multiple class loaders (also I use Groovy for tests, so very likely). So my guess is that during this parallels initializers, it erases the ClassLoader value in one thread, but access from another. But I'm unsure how to verify that, or make sure it doesn't happen.

Running Gradle with `--no-parallel` doesn't help. And I cannot reproduce the error on local machine.

What could be a cause and how to fix that?

Comment: No, it can't be line 2647; if it had been, then that's the line that would be in your stack trace. The source code you found and the version of CL you have on your classpath at runtime aren't in sync. For example, in a copy of the sources I have, 2646 is a for-each on sys_paths (an NPE would occur here if sys_paths is null).

Comment: Ah, thank you, that was a confusing part. So now it's even more clear that it's because of erasing sys_path (updated the question)